# Can't create web form using master page?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webforms, vs-web-site-project

Hi I am trying to create a website in MS VisualStudio 2013. At the moment I am trying to create a web form using the master page(which I have already created). However the 'web form using master page' is not being listed as an option(would post a photo but don't have enough reputation points). Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue some time ago. With the newer versions of .NET frameworks, you have to add "Content Page". You can find it in the Add new item list.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click the existing project name and choose add -> add new item -> web form. VS will automatically generate the .aspx and .cs files, and you can just add

```
MasterPageFile = "~/Site.Master" (or whatever name you have chosen for the site master)
```

in the `<%@ Page %>` tag at the top of the `.aspx` file you just created. This should connect the two!